# Login failed for user 'xyz'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I try to connect to my server from Windows Azure, I get an error like:

> Login failed for user 'xyz'.

My connection string in web.config file is:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="
     Server=192.164.x.xx;
     User Id=xyz;
     Password=password;
     Database=databasename"/>
```

But when I login using the same credentials with SQL Server, then I'm able to connect without any errors.

Why am I getting an error like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're problem is that on SQL Azure, the username has to be post-fixed with the server name

A proper connection string for SQL Azure should look something like this:

```
  <add name="ApplicationServices"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="
      Server=tcp:[SERVERNAME].database.windows.net,1433;
          Database=databasename;
          User ID=xyz@[SERVERNAME];
          Password=password;"/>
```